# Returning JSON not working properly

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, json

I am trying to return data from a database and convert it into json and send it back to my javascript. However its not working as planned, it returns as an array on the javascript.

**Javascript**

```
function getData(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'some url',
        crossDomain: true,
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            id: id
        },
        success: function (data) {
            var json = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            alert(data);
        },
    });
};
```

PHP

```
<?php
header("access-control-allow-origin: *");

$dbhost = 'you dont need this info';
$dbuser = 'you dont need this info';
$dbpass = 'you dont need this info';
$db     = 'you dont need this info';

$dbserver = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("Unable to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db) or die("Unable to select database: " . mysql_error());

if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
    $ID = $_POST['id'];
}
echo $ID;

$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM clubmember WHERE clubID = "' . $ID . '"');
$row    = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$name   = $row['name'];
$clubID = $row['clubID'];
$lID    = $row['lID'];
$sName  = $row['sName'];
$desc   = $row['description'];


$json = json_encode(array(
    'name' => $name,
    'clubID' => $clubID,
    'lID' => $lID,
    'sName' => $sName,
    'description' => $desc
));

echo $json;

?>
```

The javascript alerts in the form of `[object Object], [object Object]` ...
Which shouldn't be the case...

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to mysql injection

Comment: what? i didn't put the passwords to my db

Comment: Why are you echoing the $id, thats likely causing some problems too

Comment: alert(data.name), or alert(data.lID)...you should get values

Comment: If you don't know what SQL injection is, let alone how to prevent it, _you shouldn't be writing public facing code that uses MySQL_

Comment: @nshah, You don't understand what MySQL injection attacks are.  They have nothing to do with passwords.  It has to do with data becoming part of the command.  If you use prepared/parameterized queries, it fundamentally separates the command and the data, so this isn't a problem.

Comment: @nshah you should learn about prepared statements with PDO or mysqli to avoid mysql injection

Comment: @KyleK i was just echoing id for debugging purposes

Comment: I see you specify `crossDomain=true`. If it's a request to different domain, then forget about receiving a response

Comment: @ThanhTrung, ive gotten responses in other cases, only this time its not working

Comment: Do you use a debugger like element inspector ? Try to see what response you received. Most of the case is because of syntax error or notice thrown

Comment: there are no errors @ThanhTrung

Comment: @nshah . Read and learn "http://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/sql-injection/"

Answer (score 1):

Don't echo $ID in your PHP. Use jQuery's ajax dataType property and set it to json. Use default javascript json parser.

Answer (score 1):

try alerting `json` rather than `data`?

Comment: instead of alert try ``console.log(json)`` and see if it appears as an array in the console. or try ``alert(json.name)``

Comment: json.name returns undefined ?? wut

Comment: have you removed the ``echo $ID;`` from the PHP? it's probably interfering with the json

Answer (score 1):

Javascript returns an object because you are in fact alerting an object. Try `alert(data.name);`

or `alert(data.clubID);`, it will work.

Comment: but my data that is being returned is in a different format than what i echoed in the php

Comment: You are returning an associative array from PHP e.g. array('name' => x, 'age' => y); which javascript sees as an object (because it is one), even if you json_encoded it

Comment: but the array should be like 5 values long, it only holds id and name

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the data type that the ajax call is requesting, otherwise jQuery will "intelligently" detect based on the MIME type. If the ajax call receives json data, it will use it as a JavaScript object, which is why you are getting that alert.

Answer (score 1):

The .ajax() call will, if the dataType parameter is not given, "intelligently guess" what the requested page returns. 
 In the case of JSON, it will pass a JavaScript object to the success function.

After reviewing your question(s), I believe I get what you mean.
What you're expecting is a single object (looked up with SQL, as mentioned in a very insecure way) with 5 properties, name, clubID, lID, sName and description.
However, it seems that what you're getting back are multiple rows with only two properties?
What you're saying is that while the php script echo's the right values (one row) but JSON is receiving multiple values(/rows).
 Are you sure the PHP is receiving the right ID from the AJAX call?

Answer (score 1):

That is right.

The JSON is an object. a.k.a **Javascript Object Notation**. That should be in case.
It should contain your data. Try `data.*`.

By the way, if you don't clear the data coming from your users before using it with any SQL Query, that will cause trouble.

See it in action with a basic example:

```
// $_POST['id'] = '" OR 1"'
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM clubmember WHERE clubID = "'.$ID.'"');
```

Your query is now

```
SELECT * FROM clubmember WHERE clubID ="" OR 1 ""
```

Because 1 is always true, I am now able to take all of your clubmember table. Cheers.

Comment: Start using mysqli when you connect to your database. It has (and mysql had) string mysqli::real_escape_string ( string $escapestr ).

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 1):

Even if `parseJSON` returns an object, doing a console.log should show `[Object, Object, ...]` which is an array of object

Comment: yes, but it should be 1 array of 5 objects, but its multiple arrays of 2 objects each for some reason

Comment: @nshah You have 2 echo, which is wrong. Try to fix it first and see what happens. And no, you shouldn't use alert() to debug the variable, try console.log. When using alert(), the browser tends to convert the array into a string, seperated by a comma

Comment: i erased one echo
all i have is echo $json;

Comment: What's the output of console.log ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31499/discussion-between-thanh-trung-and-nshah)