# Javascript Return JSON not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

i am returning json from my php file, the php file works fine and json is echoed properly, but the problem within the js...

[image: alert output from js]

the output should be {"name":"somename", "id":"someid","l":"something","sname":"somename","desc":"longdescriptionhere"}

JAVASCRIPT

```
function getClubData(id) {
    alert(id);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'someurl',
        crossDomain: true,
        type: 'post',
        data: id,
        success: function (data) {
            var json = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            alert(data);
        },
    });
};
```

PHP

```
$json = json_encode(array('name' => $name, 'id' => $id, 'l' => $l, 'sname' => $sname, 'desc' => $desc));

echo $json;
```

i am sure the php is correct, because it echoes on the page, the correct information, its just not transferring properly back to the javascript...

Comment: what happens if you console.log(json)?

Comment: it says, [object, object, object, object, object, object]

Comment: its the wrong objects thought, you see i have a listview, and its returning info for each item in the list, not the proper json from the php file

Comment: Ok, so cant you just access it by data.id, data.name etc

Comment: Im not sure I understand what you mean

Comment: look at my comment on the answer u posted below

Comment: What's the difference to your previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/17015189/218196

Comment: In that case: Please don't ask questions twice. Voted to close as duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT / UPDATE**

Now that I actually get whats going on, and what you want...
Heres my **updated** answer

You need to give the id a key, so that on the other side your PHP script knows where to get this id....through the $_POST variable.

So your javscript...

```
function getClubData(id) {
alert(id);
$.ajax({
url: 'someurl',
crossDomain: true,
type: 'post',
data: {'theid':id},
success: function (data) {
var json = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
alert(data);


},
});

};
```

And then your php script would get that id

```
$id = $_POST['theid'];

$sql = "SELECT * from YOURTABLE WHERE ID = $id";
//and rest of your query and database stuff etc etc
```

Comment: i have 6 items in my list view, which each have a data-club-id... so whichever one is clicked on, it sends that id to the js function. so what is being alerted is the name and id of each item in the listview, not the 5 fields for whichever one is clicked

Comment: Well thats because youre just passing id into the data, youre not giving it a key or anything, how does the php know what id number you chose?

Comment: like you need to be passing {theid : id} into the data field...know what Im saying....it has to be an object

Comment: because, when an item on the list is clicked, it gets the id in a different function, then passes it on to the getData(id) function... in the function, when i alert(id), it gives me the correct id

Comment: I get that....but you need to give the id a key value for the php script to process....such as {yourkey : id }  or whatever value the PHP script is looking for in its $_POST['yourkey'] item

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31500/discussion-between-nshah-and-kylek)